# php levenstein similarity on combobox with id

Tags: php, combobox, words, levenshtein-distance

I tried to make a coincidence in a combobox with a list of categories with the first similar word that find on a register, for example:

Input a quote: "the sun is great and nobody can see it directly"

explode each word in an array "the", "sun", etc...

find the word in a category with a similar name: category "great"

Until that it's ok, but the category has an ID, so... how can I make that coincidence with the ID because it finds the word, but always saves with the first category id.

Here's my code: (EDITED by @Mike)

```
    <?php
 $rows = mysql_num_rows($RecordsetCategory);
  if($rows > 0) { mysql_data_seek($RecordsetCategory, 0);
 while ($row_RecordsetCategory = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetCategory)) { 

$input = $row_RecordsetCategory['category'];
$words  = str_word_count($quotes,1);
$shortest = -1;

foreach ($words as $word) {
    $lev = levenshtein($input, $word);
    if ($lev == 0) {
        $closest = $word;
        $shortest = 0;
        break;
    }
    if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
        $closest  = $word;
        $shortest = $lev;
    }
}

if ($shortest == 0) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row_RecordsetCategory['id']?>"><?php echo $closest;?></option>
<?php }
}
}
?>
```

But what i get is the same category for all of those quotes, when each one must have a different >> [category quotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2sL3.png)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want a `while` loop, but are using a `do` loop. Does this work better?

```
<?php

$rows = mysql_num_rows($RecordsetCategory);
if($rows > 0) {
    mysql_data_seek($RecordsetCategory, 0);

    while ($row_RecordsetCategory = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetCategory)) { 
        $input = $row_RecordsetCategory['category'];

        $chain = $quote;
        $array = explode(" ", $quote);
        $words  = $array;

        $shortest = -1;

        foreach ($words as $word) {
            $lev = levenshtein($input, $word);
            if ($lev == 0) {
                $closest = $word;
                $shortest = 0;
                break;
            }
            if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
                $closest  = $word;
                $shortest = $lev;
            }
        }

        ?><option value="<?php echo $row_RecordsetCategory['id']?>"><?php echo $closest;?></option><?php
    }

}
```

I can not say I fully understand what you are doing, but you will want to execute the query before operating off the query results.

Comment: Hi @Mike, thanks, i modify the code and edited the question, i want each quote find automatically the category with the first word coincidence between the list of words of that quote. Sorry if my english it's not really well